# magento admin product grid add category filter to admin grid without adding column

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

i am trying to filter grid by category without adding category column, is there a way by which we can do this custom filter to grid.

below is what i did

```
function prepareCollection()
{
$catIdArray = getRequest()->getParam('cat_id');
//i.e  $catIdArray = array(26, 27, 17);

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection(); 

$collection->joinField(
    'category_id',
    'catalog/category_product',
    'category_id',
    'product_id=entity_id',
    null,
    'left'
)
->addAttributeToFilter( 
    'category_id',
    array('in' => $catIdArray)
)
->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$this->setCollection($collection);
```

Here filter is working fine, but pagination doesn't work in this case. please suggest me what am i doing wrong????

Answer (score 1):

In order to fix the pagination after extending the grids in the Magento back office you need to extend **lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php**.

Copy **Db.php** to the path **app/code/local/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php** and replace the function `getSelectCountSql` with the below:-

```
public function getSelectCountSql()
{   
    $this->_renderFilters();
    $countSelect = clone $this->getSelect();
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_COUNT);
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_OFFSET);
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);

    // Count doesn't work with group by columns keep the group by 
    if(count($this->getSelect()->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP)) > 0) {
        $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP);
        $countSelect->distinct(true);
        $group = $this->getSelect()->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP);
        $countSelect->columns("COUNT(DISTINCT ".implode(", ", $group).")");
    } else {
        $countSelect->columns('COUNT(*)');
    }
    return $countSelect;
}
```